# Clustering with Hibernate: SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Could not find a SessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, jboss7.x

I have Hibernate working with a single Tomcat node, but when I try running in a cluster, I get this error:

```
SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Could not find a SessionFactory [uuid=158c1e24-039b-4406-9a9b-cebb836100d1,name=null]
java.io.InvalidObjectException: Could not find a SessionFactory [uuid=158c1e24-039b-4406-9a9b-cebb836100d1,name=null]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateSessionFactoryOnDeserialization(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1767)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.readResolve(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1747)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1091)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1786)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1894)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1894)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1894)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1894)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1485)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:987)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:446)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.startup.SipHostConfig.deployWAR(SipHostConfig.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.startup.SipHostConfig.deployWARs(SipHostConfig.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.startup.SipHostConfig.deployApps(SipHostConfig.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.startup.SipStandardEngine.start(SipStandardEngine.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.startup.SipStandardService.start(SipStandardService.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Here's my HibernateUtil class, called RecordingHibernateUtil:

```
public class RecordingHibernateUtil {

public static final String CONFIG_FILENAME = "hibernate-recording.cfg.xml";
public static final String RECORDING_DB_URL = "recording.db.url";
public static final String RECORDING_DB_DRIVER = "recording.db.driver";
public static final String RECORDING_DB_USERNAME = "recording.db.username";
public static final String RECORDING_DB_PASSWORD = "recording.db.password";

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

public static void buildSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory != null) {
        //Already configured
        return;
    }
    Properties props;
    try {
        props = DBConfiguration.getInstance().getProperties();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    Configuration config = new Configuration().configure(CONFIG_FILENAME);
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", 
            props.getProperty(RECORDING_DB_URL, 
                    props.getProperty(DBConfiguration.DB_URL)));
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", 
            props.getProperty(RECORDING_DB_DRIVER, 
                    props.getProperty(DBConfiguration.DB_DRIVER)));
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", 
            props.getProperty(RECORDING_DB_USERNAME, 
                    props.getProperty(DBConfiguration.DB_USERNAME)));
    config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", 
            props.getProperty(RECORDING_DB_PASSWORD, 
                    props.getProperty(DBConfiguration.DB_PASSWORD)));
    try {
        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
}
}
```

From internet searches, it sounded like it's trying to serialize the Hibernate SessionFactory, and to prevent this it was suggested to use JNDI lookup to get the SessionFactory.  Is this correct?  I don't know why it's trying to serialize the SessionFactory anyway.  (Right now I'm storing the SessionFactory in a static variable in a HibernateUtil class... I'd much prefer to keep it this way.)

Is it really necessary to use JNDI?  How would I go about doing this?  I need a solution that works for both Tomcat and JBoss (preferably), or a separate solution for each.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that at some point your http-session keeps a reference to the SessionFactory and it don't make sence.
The SessionFactory is referenced from each Hibernate Session, so I guess that you put a reference to an   Hibernate Session in your http-session... and this is bad.

Keep in mind that :

- an http-session is a long time living object (multiple request-response loop)
- an hibernate session is short-time living object (even if it can be done: it's quite complex to try to reuse the same Hibernate Session during more than one request).

So you must find the reference to the Hibernate Session in Http Session : use your debugger and explore the content of your http-session